# HTML video permanently muted only Firefox

Tags: html

I'm including a video in a page and have had no problems in Chrome or Safari thus far, but on Firefox the viedos are muted and the volume can't be changed. Here is the video code

```
<video src="video/test3.MOV" controls>
  <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. Here is a
</video>
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What encoding is the audio in? Does Firefox support it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the version of Firefox is too old. Only versions Firefox 21 (or Firefox 30 for Linux) and above can support video mp4. And even if it meets the required version there are still problems with Firefox support certain mp4's inside of .mov files. More information [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1115863) about the firefox issues.

Answer (score 0):

Offer other codecs. .mp4 and .webm are what I always offer. FFMpeg can transcode into these formats for you. That should fix your issue. Re: how to use FFMPeg, see [Getting Started with FFmpeg, Introduction to the FFmpeg Command Line](https://telecomputingarchitects.com/articles/ffmpeg-getting-started)

It's really not difficult at all. View page source from [here](http://rack.international/video/gmThrough.html).

```
<video controls poster="ThroughGeorgeMichaelPalaisGarnierParis.jpg">
    <source src="ThroughGeorgeMichaelPalaisGarnierParis.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="ThroughGeorgeMichaelPalaisGarnierParis.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8/VP9 or MP4 with H.264.
</video>
```